# Way to take diff of timestamp in python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to measure bootloader timing where in I need to measure SPL, U-Boot and total time ( SPL + U-Boot). My minicom console log entries looks as follows

> 

```
$ cat u-boot-2017-01 | grep -e 'U-Boot SPL 2017' -e 'U-Boot 2017.01' -e 'Starting kernel ...'
[2018-10-11 15:05:11.021] U-Boot SPL 2017.01-05786-ge0aa2fcb13 (Oct 10 2018 - 13:53:01)
[2018-10-11 15:05:11.294] U-Boot 2017.01-05786-ge0aa2fcb13 (Oct 10 2018 - 13:53:01 -0400)
[2018-10-11 15:05:12.706] Starting kernel ...
```

Now

> SPL boot time is : timestamp diff of line 1 and line 2 ( SPL start and
>   U-Boot start)
>   U-Boot boot time is : timestamp diff of line 2 and
>   line 3 ( U-Boot start and starting kernel)
>   Total time is : timestamp
>   diff of line 1 and line 3.

I see that python [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) supports Year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microseconds, milliseconds but not sure how do i convert this timestamp to timedelta. I am learning python so want to try it in there. can someone suggest how it should be done. I have to do these measurement for multiple products and multiple versions of bootloader so scripting would be nice.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the difference between `2018-10-11 15:05:11.021` and `2018-10-11 15:05:11.294`?

Comment: yes, difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much straightforward by using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), just need to make sure to use the correct format.

See the available directives [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = '2018-10-11 15:05:11.021'
end_time = '2018-10-11 15:05:11.294'

FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

print(datetime.strptime(end_time, FORMAT) - datetime.strptime(start_time, FORMAT))
# 0:00:00.273000
```

Comment: isn't `%f` for microseconds and not milliseconds ? timestamp I have mentioned has milliseconds in it. So I need to use some other format right ?